# Prove if the following sets are topologies in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, integers

I've been solving the following problem from the start of my general topology course, and I'd like to check if my answers are correct. The problem is:

> Study if the following sets of subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ are topologies
> or not:
>
> 1. $\mathcal{A}_1=\{\emptyset,\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\{2,3,-4\},\{1,2,3,-4\},\mathbb{Z}\}$
> 2. $\mathcal{A}_2=\{\emptyset\}\cup\{n\mathbb{Z}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
> 3. $\mathcal{A}_3=\{A\subset\mathbb{Z}: 0 \in A\}$
> 4. $\mathcal{A}_4=\{A\subset Z: A \text{ is infinite }\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$

My solutions (I concluded no one is a topology in $\mathbb{Z}$, all using the definition of topology):

1. NOT, because $\{1,2\}\cap\{2,3,-4\}=\{2\}\notin \mathcal{A}_1.$
2. NOT, because $\nexists\phantom{,} n\in\mathbb{N}: n\mathbb{Z}=3\mathbb{Z}\cup 7\mathbb{Z}$ (this is because $\text{gcd}(3,7)=1$, but $1\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}\neq3\mathbb{Z}\cup 7\mathbb{Z}$).
3. NOT, because $\emptyset\notin\mathcal{A}_3.$
4. NOT, because if we consider the sets
   $$A=\{z\in\mathbb{Z} : z \text{ is even}\}$$
   $$B=\{z\in\mathbb{Z} : z \text{ is odd}\}\cup \{2\},$$
   it's clear that both $A,B\in\mathcal{A}_4$ because both are infinite sets, but $A\cap B=\{2\}$, hence we conclude that $A\cap B\notin\mathcal{A}_4$ (because $\{2\}$ is a finite set), so we conclude $\mathcal{A}_4$ is NOT a topology in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Are my solutions correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, this fine.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Great, thanks!

Comment: Perfecto!!!!!!!

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but I am not quite sure about the third one. I would consider the empty set to be a subset of every set.

Comment: @Octavius but $0\notin \emptyset$, so $\emptyset\notin\mathcal{A}_3$.

Comment: Well but for every subset $S \subseteq A$ it holds that $A \backslash S \subseteq A$. Thus, for $S = A \Longrightarrow A \backslash A = \emptyset \subseteq A$.


The empty set is indeed a subset of every set, otherwise it would lead to contradictions (e.g. consider the sets $X = \{ 1 \}$ and $Y = \{ 2 \}$ and assume that $\emptyset \notin X$. Obviously $X \cap Y = \emptyset$, but $X \cap Y := \{ x : x \in X \land x \in Y \}$ so $\emptyset \subseteq X \cap Y$ and therefore $\emptyset \in X \land \emptyset \in Y$.

Comment: @Octavius But it's not the same. $\mathcal{A}_3$ does not need to verify that $\emptyset\subset\mathcal{A}_3$, but rather that $\emptyset\in\mathcal{A}_3$ (notice the difference here between "$\subset$" and "$\in$"), and it's true that for every set $X$ then $\emptyset\subset X$, but in general $\emptyset\notin X$. Thanks for your comment anyway!